# Three.js, Raycaster, array of rays?

Tags: three.js, raycasting

I have two rays, one highlights a mesh when is in the center of camera and the other one highlights a mesh on click. [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/huboyaxane/edit?html,output):

```
// ...
raycasterClick = new THREE.Raycaster();
raycasterCenter = new THREE.Raycaster();
// ...
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  // ...
  // clear intersected
  for (var i = 0; i < INTERSECTED.length; i++) {
    INTERSECTED[i].material.emissive.setHex(INTERSECTED[i].currentHex);
    INTERSECTED.splice(i, 1);
  }
  // click
  raycasterClick.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  var intersects = raycasterClick.intersectObjects(scene.children);
  for (var i = 0; clickedIn && i < intersects.length; i++) {
    var length = INTERSECTED.push(intersects[0].object) - 1;
    INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED[length].material.emissive.getHex();
    INTERSECTED[length].material.emissive.setHex(0xff0000);
  }
  // center
  raycasterCenter.setFromCamera(center, camera);
  var intersects = raycasterCenter.intersectObjects(scene.children);
  for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
    var length = INTERSECTED.push(intersects[0].object) - 1;
    INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED[length].material.emissive.getHex();
    INTERSECTED[length].material.emissive.setHex(0xff0000);
    if(intersects[0].distance<=2&&controls.moveZ==-1)controls.moveZ=0;
  }
  // ...
}
```

I was wondering if I have to call a `new THREE.Raycaster()` for each ray like in my example above or there is a way to only call it once by making an array of rays. With an array I would have to loop only once through all the `scene.children`. I'm thinking of resources.

**How to create an array of rays in Three.js?**

Comment: I don't think there is an array of rays. even though you can construct an array, the raycaster intersection check will check each ray with each mesh, always need to check 2 * n(n:the amount of scene.children) times

Comment: Maybe I didn't get something in this conception of array of rays. Do you mean something like this: `raycaster.setFromCamera([center, mouse], camera);`? But in case, when you get `INTERSECTED`, how will you differentiate which object was intersected with which ray? It will need rewriting of `Raycaster.js`. And thinking of resources is necessery only when it's really needed.

Comment: I'm new to Three.js and is pretty complex and I was trying to think ahead. Yes ,something like `raycaster.setFromCamera([center, mouse], camera)` I had in mind, and in `intersectObjects(scene.children)`to find this ray(maybe by index) with that object. Then I guess the matter is closed.